How to wrap text in Sunburst chart?
I want to wrap the text on this sunburst chart so it is displayed in 2 or more lines instead of 1. The test data is not the best, but it shows the scenario am facing - Link to VegaEditor.
I have tried to split and join it, but with no results.
Slice and join, but with no result

Found a solution by splitting the text into 2 parts and placing them one on top of the other.

You're splitting on space but none of the words contain spaces.

Hey! This is just the test data (from the Sunburst example chart). My data has words divided by spaces and the text still does not wrap. I was not able to copy my own data over into the Editor to show it.

You pass an array to the text encoding for it to wrap. You were not doing that in your original spec.
